# Count specific pattern inside text

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a huge file I want to use as shell command to count the number of the word 'new' in the file
a tried to use `wc`  and `grep` but I get the number of lines that contain pattern only

Comment: please update the quesiton to include sample input file, the code (`wc`, `grep`) you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: with GNU grep? `grep -ow 'new' file.txt | wc -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @Fravadona's suggestion:

```
grep -ow new file.txt | wc -l
```

`-o` means "print only the matches, one per line"

`-w` means "only match if it's a full word" and avoid matching for e.g. `newOrder`

`wc -l` counts the amount of lines grep did output